# Is it possible using adb via root to grant the permission of PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS?

Tags: android, adb, android-permissions

### Background

adb can be used to grant various permissions, but this permission is special, and using it for this permission via root doesn't seem to work properly:

```
pm grant packageName android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS
```

### The problem

The OS says it's granted, but the app itself can't detect it.

### What I've found

See code of the app to check it out:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @JvmStatic
        fun hasPermission(context: Context): Boolean {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                return false
            val appOps = context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE) as AppOpsManager
            val mode = appOps.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS, android.os.Process.myUid(), context.getPackageName())
            val granted = if (mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_DEFAULT) {
                (context.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            } else {
                (mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED)
            }
            return granted
//            val appOps = context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE) as AppOpsManager
//            val granted = appOps.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS, android.os.Process.myUid(), context.packageName) == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED
//            return granted
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            val granted = hasPermission(this@MainActivity)
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "has permission:" + granted, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        button2.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS))
        }
    // extra code for granting the app the permission using root
    }
}
```

**manifest:**

```
<manifest package="com.example.user.myapplication" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="check the permission using below buttons before and after you grant it via root"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="check permission via code"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="go to settings screen"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

### The question

How come if I use adb via PC, it works fine, yet if I use root within the app itself, I get a weird result, that the OS says the app got the permission, yet the app can't detect it ?

What should I do in order to truly grant the permission using root, within the app, and also detect it properly ?

Comment: i do not think you can grant system app permissions to any app that way.

Comment: @MehulMohan I was hoping there is a way nevertheless. Maybe using root? BTW, I don't think it's classified as a system permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `adb shell pm grant [PACKAGE_NAME] android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` worked for me on several devices.

Make sure you added the following to the `AndroidManifest`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
  tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
```

---

I was also able to use root to grant the permission. Again, the app must declare the permission in the `AndroidManifest`.

You can use [AndroidShell](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidShell) to run the command as root. Example:

```
String packageName = context.getPackageName();
CommandResult result = Shell.SU.run("pm grant " + packageName + " android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS");
```

---

As mentioned by Sagar, you can also ask the user to grant the permission in the settings app, which is Google's recommended way to do this[:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6m87WvCALMQ)

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS));
```

Comment: I've just tested it. Even though the UI of the OS says the permission is granted (using the Intent), the app can't detect it. Tested various ways to check if the permission is granted , here: stackoverflow.com/q/28921136/878126 . For the app, the permission seems like it isn't really granted.

Comment: @androiddeveloper See this gist: https://gist.github.com/jaredrummler/72e49ee8529e9d19d1b2392202ac39c1

I was able to use adb and UsageStatsManager returned results and permission check passed on an unrooted Samsun S8

Comment: I am talking about using this command from within the app itself (using root). Please try it there. I've tested it and the app failed to detect that it has this permission.

Comment: @androiddeveloper Have you tried using the [AndroidShell](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidShell) library to run the command as root? If so, please log `stderr` and `stdout` and paste the resutls.

Comment: This is odd. You test the permission in a way that I remember didn't work, so this is why I've asked about this in the past, and got these answers: stackoverflow.com/q/28921136/878126 . On which Android versions have you tried it? I only have Android P to test on currently, and it seems to work fine using your code. Can you please test on Android 5.1 and above (API 22) ? On which one have you tested it?

Comment: I've just asked someone to test it. Seems it works well on Android 6.0 and 7.1.2. I think the issue was on 5.1. Can you please check it out?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Tested on a rooted HTC M8 running Android 5.1 and it is working. After running `pm grant $packageName  android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` as root the permission check returned true.

Comment: How odd. I was sure I had an issue with this in the past, which is why I had to ask about it. Anyway, thank you. I will grant you the bounty. Please do consider answering me if I have an issue with this. Also, please consider telling me now why I've failed to use the "AndroidShell" library, even though I use something else.

Comment: Can you also test it on Android 5.0 ?

Comment: I don't have a rooted device running Android 5.0 but I don't see why this wouldn't work. SystemPanel on the Google Play store uses the same methods above to grant PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS permission.

Answer (score 0):

In case you face the same problem I found this answer
[Grant PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS permission through adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719273/grant-package-usage-stats-permission-through-adb)
and combined Jared Rummler's answer it finally worked for me on a rooted device.

```
public void setMissingPermissions(String pkg){
        try {
            String[] Commands = new String[]{"su", "-c", "pm", "grant", pkg, "android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"};
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Commands);
            Commands = new String[]{"su", "-c", "appops", "set", pkg, "GET_USAGE_STATS", "allow"};
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Commands);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
}
```

Comment: actually i tried this but not working