# Grant PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS permission through adb

Tags: android, adb

`adb shell pm grant x.y.z android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS`

This is the command to grant `PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` permission through adb, but it only works if I have never toggled this permission in native settings.

The same thing happens to `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission, while there is a better command `adb shell appops set x.y.z SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW allow` to do it effectively.

The problem is I didn't find another command to toggle `PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` permission.

Comment: I was also searching the same but didn't find any :(

Comment: https://automationchronicles.com/set-permissions-via-adb-and-appops-command/

This is a good article, also mentioned something about "uid mode". It helped me today with a case when `adb shell appops set x.y.z SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW allow` doesn't work, on the following case


`adb shell appops get x.y.z SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
Uid mode: SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW: deny
SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW: allow; time=+3d22h41m24s534ms ago; rejectTime=+3d22h23m58s42ms ago; duration=+16m18s321ms`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `android:get_usage_stats` using `appops`

`adb shell appops set x.y.z android:get_usage_stats allow`

Comment: It works!
The value is listed here.
[AppOpsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AppOpsManager#OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS)

Comment: `adb shell appops set x.y.z GET_USAGE_STATS allow` this one also works.

Answer (score 0):

adb shell dumpsys dropbox --print system_server_watchdog

Answer (score -2):

Run the following command:

```bash
adb shell pm grant com.arumcomm.androiddevinfo android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS
```

Comment: This would not work after you changed it from Android native settings.

Answer (score -2):

```
com.arumcomm.androiddevinfo android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS
com.arumcomm.androiddevinfo android.permission.READ_LOGS
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.